# Como chamar arquivos no localhost

Tags: javascript, css, localhost

Instalei um script feito em codelgniter em localhost, mais o site fica inteiro sem formatação e sem funções funcionando, acredito que não não está fazendo a chamada correta dos arquivos css, js.

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="http://www.localhost/assets/img/favicon.png" />

<!-- css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.localhost/assets/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.localhost/assets/css/foundation.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.localhost/assets/css/jquery.sidr.dark.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.localhost/assets/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.localhost/assets/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.localhost/assets/tooltipster/dist/css/tooltipster.bundle.min.css">      
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.localhost/assets/css/app.css">

<!-- js -->
<script src="http://www.localhost/assets/js/vendor/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.localhost/assets/js/vendor/pace.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.localhost/assets/js/vendor/what-input.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.localhost/assets/js/vendor/foundation.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.localhost/assets/js/vendor/foneMascara.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.localhost/assets/js/vendor/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.localhost/assets/js/vendor/jquery.sidr.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.localhost/assets/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.localhost/assets/js/vendor/jquery.paginate.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.localhost/assets/tooltipster/dist/js/tooltipster.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.localhost/assets/js/app.min.js"></script>
```

O endereço dos aquivos no localhost é:

> localhost/panamerico

e nas chamadas não está aparecendo a pasta "panamerico".

Comment: Configura seu script passando o diretório 'panamerico'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

se os arquivos estão na mesma pasta que seu html principal, você pode chamar o nome da pasta do arquivo e o nome do arquivo.
Exemplo`<link rel="nome_da_pasta/nome_arquivo>"`